# laravel form post / patch

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to submit a form but laravel throws an error in this line.
Please help me determine what the issue is.

```
    <form method = '{{isset($address)? 'PATCH': 'POST}}'  action="{{isset($address) ? 'acount/$id' : '/account'}}" >
```

> error :syntax error, unexpected 'action' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')'

Comment: You can inspect the element from dev tool and as the quotes are not properly inserted that will be the issue.

Comment: You can inspect the element from dev tool and as the quotes are not properly inserted that will be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the quotes properly. Use it like this:

```
<form method="{{ isset($address) ? 'PATCH': 'POST' }}" action="{{ isset($address) ? 'acount/'.$id : '/account' }}" >
```

Comment: acctually laravel generating this code at backend:     <form method = "<?php echo e(isset($address)? 'PATCH': 'POST'); ?>"  action="<?php echo e(isset($address) ? 'account/$id' : '/account'); ?>" >

Comment: I have tried this code and it is working. You are still using 'account/$id', instead use 'account/'.$id.

Comment: If still you are getting error then please attach screenshot and a bit of more code around this form.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form method = "POST" action="{{isset($address) ? 'acount/$id' : '/account'}}" >

{{ (isset($address)) ? method_field('PUT') : '' }}
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

Comment: Have you try this?